# enabling performance monitoring register to user access mode?

Tags: arm

I have written code to enable performance monitoring register as user accessible by setting bit as 1. I getting ARM_BAD_INSTRUCTION at MCR instruction and MRC is going fine.

I am using armv7(cortex a5)

.cfi_startproc

```
MRC     p15, 0, r0, c9, c14, 0  @ Read PMUSERENR Register
ORR     r0, r0, #0x01           @ Set EN bit (bit 0)
MCR     p15, 0, r0, c9, c14, 0  @ Write PMUSERENR Register
ISB                             @ Synchronize context
```

BX      lr
.cfi_endproc

Comment: Firstly, where are you running this code from? Userspace?

Comment: yes i running from userspace

Comment: yes i running from Userspace and codded in XCODE

Comment: Right. Now consider what would be the point of having an "enable access from unprivileged modes" register which could itself be freely modified from unprivileged modes. Nobody keeps their house keys on a hook on the _outside_ of their front door...

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I am new to arm assembly code just i want calculate number of cycles taken by a function for that i have seen some where that by using "performance monitoring register unit"(PMU) we can count number of cycles. But to access this register we need to set "PMUSERENR" register by using  above code. But in this instruction, code is crashing because i saw in arm user manual MCR operation works only in privileged mode.  MCR     p15, 0, r0, c9, c14, 0                             please provide the solution for above problem. I am running code on ios 32 bit device.

Answer (score 1):

[As per the documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHIFGDG.html), PMUSERENR is only writeable from privileged modes, thus an attempt to write to it from unprivileged userspace will indeed raise an undefined instruction exception.

If you want to enable userspace access, you need to do it from the kernel (or possibly from a hypervisor/firmware in the case of a kernel which doesn't know about PMUs itself).

If you don't have control of any such privileged software, well then you're not getting yourself direct access, because that's rather the point of the notion of privilege. What you might have, however, is some userspace API provided by the OS - such as [perf events](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) on Linux - to let you profile and measure stuff without the hassle of managing the hardware directly; frankly that's usually the better option even if you *could* enable direct access, because userspace still has no way to properly handle all the necessary event filtering, scheduling, overflow interrupts, etc. on a multitasking system.

Comment: Then is there any API provided by ios for such type of access

Comment: @ravi I have no idea. I could go and hunt through all the iOS developer documentation to find out, but then equally so could you...

Comment: And you have any idea how we can calculate the number cycles taken by any function in arm assembly.                                                                         I am using XCODE and running on ios(arm v7) in a mac

Comment: I'm still a little curious as to what exactly you expect "the number of cycles taken by a function" to mean - it's going to vary depending on state external to that function (conditional statements, cache misses, etc); it doesn't represent an absolute time because of dynamic frequency scaling; it doesn't represent a latency because the whole task could be scheduled out for an indeterminate length of time part-way through execution. All in all I don't really see what you would _do_ with that number if you had it, and how it could be more meaningful than just using the XCode profiler normally.